# Insert instance of ofstream to container

Tags: c++, design-patterns, copy-constructor, ofstream

I created my a class `file` which is a wrapper for `std::ofstream`. I created a `Container` to contain all the instances of `file`.

```
class file
{
private:
      std::ofstream ofs;

public:
      void open(std::string filename);
      void write(std::string s);
      void close();
};

class Container
{
private:
  std::map<int, file> m;


public:
      void insert(file f,int i)
      {
            m.insert(std::pair<int,file> (i,f));
      }
      void get(int i)
      {
            m.at(i);
      }
};
```

However, there is an issue in this code. In the `insert` method I am attempting to copy a `std::pair<int,file>` which cannot be done as the copy constructor of `std::ofstream` is deleted (see compilation error below).

**I would like to successively add instances of `file` in a container. How can I do that?**

---

Here is the compilation error

```
In file included from src/test.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:216:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:439:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:627:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/utility:274:23: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of
      'file'
        : first(__x), second(__y) {}
                      ^      ~~~
src/test.cpp:35:22: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::pair<int, file>::pair' requested here
            m.insert(std::pair<int,file> (i,f));
                     ^
src/test.cpp:9:21: note: copy constructor of 'file' is implicitly deleted because field 'ofs' has a deleted copy constructor
      std::ofstream ofs;
                    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/fstream:1168:5: note: copy constructor is implicitly deleted because
      'basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >' has a user-declared move constructor
    basic_ofstream(basic_ofstream&& __rhs);
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: How do you call the `Container::insert` method in your main code?

Comment: I did not realize that would matter. `Container` is a singleton, I use `MyContainer.insert(file, index)`.

Comment: And how do you create the `file` you insert? Do you want to make a copy of it or just put it into the `Container`? Could you show us a typical example of a `file` creation and insertion inside the container?

Comment: I create the file using the constructor of `file` and then I want to move (I realize I might have used an important keyword here) it to the `Container` (before the scope of `file` reaches its end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to kind of initialize your `Container` with `file` without copying them, then you could rely on the move-constructor of `std::ofstream`:

```
void insert(file &&f, int i)
{
    m.insert(std::pair<int,file>(i, std::move(f)));
}
```

Then you would do the following:

```
cont.insert(file{}, 0); // Construct a file when inserting, you already have an rvalue
```

Or:

```
file myfile;
myfile.open(...); // Do whatever you want with myfile...
cont.insert(std::move(myfile), 0); // And then move it, as long as you are not using if after
```

---

If your `file` is not move-constructible, you could construct it in place:

```
template <typename... Args>
void insert(int i, Args&&... args) {
    m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::tuple<int>(i),
              std::tuple<Args>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

---

Also, if you want to insert default-initialized file (like in the first example), you could simply do:

```
void insert(int i)
{
    m[i];
}
```